# can we set a password for particular iOS application when uninstall?

Tags: ios

i want to set password on my application while installing, the password will be set by user after installation complete and when someone uninstall application it will ask the same password.

Comment: This is not a feature supported by iOS.

Comment: so we cannot do like this?

Comment: @seggy no we can't.

Comment: thank you rmaddy & nayem but still i am finding another way